# Receiving obscure data after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dropbox, network-monitoring

I upgraded to 14.04 recently (obviously). Since the upgrade, I started noticing that my internet was extremely slow for the first couple of minutes.

Checking the system monitor, it seems that my system downloads about 25MB after I connect to the internet, using the whole downstream. How can I check what process is requesting the download?

**Update**. nethogs tells me that the service requesting the download is /usr/bin/python. So, it looks like a python script is downloading about 25MB every time I establish an  internet connection, which doesn't occur when I disable dropbox. What file would dropbox need to download every day? How can I track down the downloaded file?

Comment: Probably nethogs? http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, with nethogs I identified that the culprit is a python script. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox may just be checking for updates and looking for any updated files. Not sure if this is because you have a lot of files or if 25MB is standard. You can try Wireshark to take a close look at the network traffic (not sure what you could expect to find though).

You can see what the most recently updated files are with the method answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566310/how-to-recursively-find-and-list-the-latest-modified-files-in-a-directory-with-s